# IRC Bot - flood protection (python)

Tags: python, string, irc

```
  if data.find('PRIVMSG') != -1:
     nick = data.split('!')[ 0 ].replace(':','')
     text = ''
     if data.count(text) >= 200:
        sck.send('KICK ' + " " + chan + " :" 'flooding' + '\r\n')
```

I'm trying to code a flood protection for the bot, I want it to kick a user if he enters more then 200 characters, how can I make it so it can read the other lines instead of just the first line? and the code above doesn't work, it doesnt kick the user but if I change the `sck.send()` to `sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " :" 'flooding' + '\r\n')` it works.

fixed the kicking problem, and the code works now, but it only reads the first line, not sure how to make it read the other lines if the user keeps flooding the channel.

```
  if data.find('PRIVMSG') != -1:
     nick = data.split('!')[ 0 ].replace(':','')
     text = ''
     if data.count(text) >= 200:
        sck.send('KICK ' + " " + chan + " " + nick + " :" 'flooding' + '\r\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, the colon is a reserved character in the IRC protocol. That is, the first colon in a server message denotes the start of user-supplied data (that's also why ":" is not allowed in nicks/channel names). Hence, it suffices to search for the first colon and calculate the length of the remaining string.

Furthermore, `data.find('PRIVMSG')` is pretty unreliable. What if a user types the word "PRIVMSG" in regular channel conversation? Go look up the IRC RFC, it specifies the format of PRIVMSGs in detail.

Besides, you should be a little more specific. What exactly is the problem you're facing? Extracting the nick? Calculating the message length? Connecting to IRC?

Comment: calculating the message length